# Amazon Quicksight - how to calculate Percentage of Total UNIQUE values?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

How to calculate percent of count of UNIQUE values?
E.g. I have a dataset with people who can pick multiple symptoms (i.e each person can have 0 to 10 values).

```
person 1 - symptom A, B
person 2 - symptom B, C, D
person 3 - no symptoms
person 4 - symptom A
```

etc.
E.g. if total UNIQUE count of people is 4 and 2 of them have picked symptom A, then I'd like to see:
A = 2/4 = 50%
Currently QuickSight is able to calculate shares based on total count of people (not unique count) as one person can have multiple symptoms, so A is 2/6 = 33% (not what I need).

As much as I've tried, QuickSight doesn't enable that??